# set a href attribute on svg path

Tags: html, svg

I have this code

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" viewBox="20 0 970 960" enable-background="new 20 0 970 960" xml:space="preserve">
    <g class="border">
        <path class="City1" d="......" /> 
        <path class="City2" d="......" />
        <path class="City3" d="......" />              
        <path class="City4" d="......" />           
    </g>
</svg>
```

I need that set a href attribute `<a href="#..."></a>` on every patch .
like this

```
<a href="#...">
    <path class="City1" d="......" />
</a> 
<a href="#...">
    <path class="City2" d="......" />
</a>
<a href="#...">
    <path class="City3" d="......" />
</a>             
<a href="#...">
    <path class="City4" d="......" />
</a>
```

but doesn't work . So what do u guys suggest I should do ?

Comment: What doesn't work? Show us the code you've written that tries to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For SVG `<a>` elements, you need to use `xlink:href` instead of just `href`.

```
<a xlink:href="#..."><path class="City1" d="......" /></a>
```

Comment: In late 2021 this `xlink:href` is already deprecated for the standard `a href`